# Convert CSV to Nested JSON using / header delimiter

Tags: python, node.js, json, bash, jq

My CSV headers look something like

| from/email | to/0/email | personalization/0/email/ | personalization/0/data/first_name | personalization/0/data/company_name | personalization/0/data/job_title | template_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |

Output should be:

```
[
 {
   "from": {
      "email": "me@x.com",
      "name": "Me"
   },
   "to": [
      {
         "email": "mike@x.com"
      }
   ],
   "personalization": [
      {
         "email": "mike@x.com",
         "data": {
            "first_name": "Mike",
            "company_name": "X.com",
            "job_title": "Chef"
         }
      }
   ],
   "template_id": "123456"
},
```

I tried

```
csvjson input.csv output.csv
```

```
csvtojson input.csv output.csv
```

```
csv2json input.csv output.csv
```

```
python3 app.py

import csv 
import json 

def csv_to_json(csvFilePath, jsonFilePath):
    jsonArray = []
      
    #read csv file
    with open(csvFilePath, encoding='utf-8') as csvf: 
        #load csv file data using csv library's dictionary reader
        csvReader = csv.DictReader(csvf) 

        #convert each csv row into python dict
        for row in csvReader: 
            #add this python dict to json array
            jsonArray.append(row)
  
    #convert python jsonArray to JSON String and write to file
    with open(jsonFilePath, 'w', encoding='utf-8') as jsonf: 
        jsonString = json.dumps(jsonArray, indent=4)
        jsonf.write(jsonString)
          
csvFilePath = r'outputt1.csv'
jsonFilePath = r'outputt1.json'
csv_to_json(csvFilePath, jsonFilePath)
```

```
node app.js

const CSVToJSON = require('csvtojson');

// convert users.csv file to JSON array
CSVToJSON().fromFile('outputt1.csv')
    .then(from => {

        // from is a JSON array
        // log the JSON array
        console.log(from);
    }).catch(err => {
        // log error if any
        console.log(err);
    });
```

All output some variation of single-line JSON with no nesting.

The only thing that worked was uploading it to https://www.convertcsv.com/csv-to-json.htm and converting each file by hand, but that is obviously not a solution.

I have seen a post recommending Choetl.Json for this exact purpose but was unable to install it on mac

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: SO is not `dial-a-coder`.

Comment: My bad everyone please see edits

Comment: @Daweo post updated

Comment: Showing the headers is good, but you need to provide 1 or 2 rows of data. We, the people who want to help you, have nothing to test with.

Comment: Where does .from.name come from? it's not a header

Comment: Use www.convertcsv.io which is the API site for convertcsv.com

Answer (score 1):

Your problem should be broken down into two parts: parsing CSV data for conversion into JSON, and building a JSON structure following path-like descriptors.

For the first part, it is necessary to clarify the formatting of the CSV input, as there is no general standard for CSV, just a fundamental description in the [RFC 4180 proposal](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc4180) and a lot of adoptions tailored to specific use cases or data types. As you didn't provide any actual CSV content, let's assume for the sake of simplicity that records are separated by newlines, fields are separated by commas, and field delimiters are not present as the data itself never contains any of these separators. Let's further assume that all records have the exact same number of fields, and that exactly one of them (namely the first) represents the headers. You may want to adjust these assumptions to your actual CSV data.

```sh
cat input.csv
```

```
from/email,to/0/email,personalization/0/email,personalization/0/data/first_name,personalization/0/data/company_name,personalization/0/data/job_title,template_id
me@x.com,mike@x.com,mike@x.com,Mike,X.com,Chef,123456
```

Based on this formatting, you can read in the CSV data using the `--raw-input` or `-R` option which streams in each newline-separated segment of raw text as a JSON string input. Ideally, your filter should then convert each input string record into an array of string fields by splitting at the comma, e.g. using the `/` operator:

```sh
jq -R '. / ","' input.csv
```

```json
[
  "from/email",
  "to/0/email",
  "personalization/0/email",
  "personalization/0/data/first_name",
  "personalization/0/data/company_name",
  "personalization/0/data/job_title",
  "template_id"
]
[
  "me@x.com",
  "mike@x.com",
  "mike@x.com",
  "Mike",
  "X.com",
  "Chef",
  "123456"
]
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/2FL2J9_wr_)

As for the second part, you can now easily process these JSON arrays. In order to treat the first one (the headers) separately, you could use the `--slurp` or `-s` option which turns the input stream into an array whose elements can then be accessed using indices. Also, the `setpath` builtin comes in handy as it can set values within a JSON structure described as an array of strings and integers representing object fields and array indices, just as you do in your headers. This leaves you turning the header strings into such arrays by splitting at "/" and converting number-like segments into actual numbers. Finally, to successively build up your JSON objects you could iterate through the record fields using a `reduce` statement and align the record fields to their corresponding header fields using `transpose`:

```sh
… | jq -s '
  (.[0] | map(. / "/" | map(tonumber? // .))) as $headers
  | .[1:] | map(
    reduce ([$headers, .] | transpose[]) as [$path, $value] (
      {}; setpath($path; $value)
    )
  )
'
```

```json
[
  {
    "from": {
      "email": "me@x.com"
    },
    "to": [
      {
        "email": "mike@x.com"
      }
    ],
    "personalization": [
      {
        "email": "mike@x.com",
        "data": {
          "first_name": "Mike",
          "company_name": "X.com",
          "job_title": "Chef"
        }
      }
    ],
    "template_id": "123456"
  }
]
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/8_yG8UH6rp)

Notes

- My showcase disregards the fact that your sample JSON output also provides an additional field `name` under the top-level field `from` because your sample CSV input headers don't include a matching field `from/name`
- To emphasize the bipartite nature of this approach, I concluded with two cascading invocations of jq. This generally could (and mostly should) be combined into one. However, as combining the options `--raw-input` and `--slurp` would alter jq's read-in behaviour, you'd rather want to add the `--null-input` or `-n` option with `[inputs | …]` in the first filter which lets you dismiss the `--slurp` option in the second: `jq -Rn '[inputs / "/"] | …'` ([Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/dFUfMv-WHP))

Comment: Thank you pmf sorry if I'm being dumb but what does ... | mean?

Comment: "…" should represent the previous invocation of jq. If you stay with two invocations (see the second note at the end), you'd make the first call and pipe its output into the second: `jq -R '. / ","' input.csv | jq -s '…'` (here, the "…" represents the body of the second call which was too long to replicate here). But consider applying said note to combine them into one.

Comment: Hi pmf I tried this and the output was ```jq: error (at <stdin>:803): Path must be specified as an array```

Comment: You're not giving any clues as for why this could happen. Take glenn jackman's [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70988508/convert-csv-to-nested-json-using-header-delimiter/70992226?noredirect=1#comment125494368_70988508) to heart and "provide 1 or 2 rows of data".